# Retrieve annotation for file using GEOquery

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I want to retrieve the annotation for a file using GEOquery. One way I read was using fData(), so:

```
geoFile<-getGEO("GSE99511")
fData(geoFile)
```

But then I get the error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘fData’ for signature ‘"list"’
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The link in the comment from @ChiPak is for `fdata` from the `fda.usc` package; nothing to do with `fData` from the `GEOquery` package.

Comment: I see...thanks for the clarification...I'll delete my original comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: if you want the "annotation file name" (the GPL platform, presumably), the correct method is `annotation()`.

The error tells you the problem: `geoFile` is a list and `fData` expects some other kind of object. `?fData` will tell you what it expects.

If you type `names(geoFile)`, you'll probably see:

```
[1] "GSE99511_series_matrix.txt.gz"
```

If you type `str(geoFile)` or better, install and load `dplyr` and then `glimpse(geoFile)`, you'll see the structure of the object.

All of that tells you that you need to supply the first element of the list `geoFile` to `fData`:

```
head(fData(geoFile$GSE99511_series_matrix.txt.gz))
```

and you'll want to use `head()` or `glimpse()`, otherwise thousands of lines will print to the terminal.

Comment: I tried head(fData()) but that doesn't give me the annotation file name. If you type geoFile (or geoFile$GSE99511_series_matrix.txt.gz) in the command line, you'll see "Annotation" at the end. That line is what I want to retrieve.

Comment: OK, then use `annotation(g$GSE1001_series_matrix.txt.gz)`. Your question was about an error using `fData`.